# Segmentation fault when using pointers in between functions

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting a segmentation fault when assigning the value stored at a pointer to a local variable in a function. I have a hunch that I'm handling pointers poorly, but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Any ideas? Thanks!

I've tried adding breakpoints, and I've determine that the actual seg fault happens at "int i = *AlignCounter;"

When looking at the variables window, I see this:
[image: Variables Window in VSC Debugger]

Here's the function where the seg fault happens:

```
void align_S_T(int *StringCounterS, int 
*StringCounterT, int *AlignCounter, char *StringS, char 
*StringT, char *AlignmentS, char *AlignmentT)
{
//Local Variables
int i = *AlignCounter; //<--Seg Fault Line
int s = *StringCounterS;
int t = *StringCounterT;
//Set Strings
AlignmentS[i] = StringS[s];
AlignmentT[i] = StringT[t];

//Increment Counters
*AlignCounter++;
*StringCounterS++;
*StringCounterT++;

}
```

Here's how the pointers are created and allocated in main:

```
    int* StringCounterT; //T String Counter
    int* AlignCounter; //Align Counter

    StringCounterS=0;
    StringCounterT=0;
    AlignCounter=0;
```

Comment: What are the values of giving the parameter AlignCounter when you use the  align_S_T function?

Comment: Do you think you are allowed to access the memory location at `0x0` (at the very base of the *System Reserved* memory range)? What do you think is stored there? `int i = *AlignCounter; //<--Seg Fault Line` is a good indication of the answer to the first question. In other words `AlignCounter=0;` stores the *Address* `0` as the value for `AlignCounter` and when you attempt to access the memory location you have no right to access, BAM SegFault.

Comment: before use the `align_S_T` function  did you allocated dynamic memory to `AlignCounter`?

Comment: @Miguel, no I just declared the pointer.

Comment: What do you think happens when you try to dereference a pointer pointing to nowhere then?

Answer (score 1):

You are indicating that AlignCounter points to address 0 (AlignCounter=0;), then, inside  align_S_T() you are trying to get the value stored inside this adress with "*" operator(int i = *AlignCounter;). You cannt do this because it is not a valid address (try to point AlignCounter to a declared integer before calling align_S_T(), the segFault goes to next line, rss, same thing).

```
void align_S_T(int *StringCounterS, int 
*StringCounterT, int *AlignCounter, char *StringS, char 
*StringT, char *AlignmentS, char *AlignmentT)
{
//Local Variables
int i = *AlignCounter;
int s = *StringCounterS;  //<--Seg Fault Line!!
int t = *StringCounterT;
//Set Strings
AlignmentS[i] = StringS[s];
AlignmentT[i] = StringT[t];

//Increment Counters
*AlignCounter++;
*StringCounterS++;
*StringCounterT++;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int* StringCounterT; //T String Counter
     int* StringCounterS; //T String Counter
     int* AlignCounter; //Align Counter
     char *a, *b, *c, *d;
     int x;

     a = b = c = d = "";
     x = 10;

     StringCounterS=0;
     StringCounterT=0;
     AlignCounter=&x;  

     align_S_T(StringCounterS, StringCounterT, AlignCounter, a, b, c, d);
     return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have isolated your problem, you need to assign dynamic memory or static to `AlignCounter` variable before calling the function `align_S_T` as you can see in the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void  align_S_T(int *AlignCounter)
{
   int i = *AlignCounter;
   *AlignCounter++;
}

int main()
{
   // Dynamic memory
   int *AlignCounter=NULL;
   AlignCounter = (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); 
   *AlignCounter=0;
   // static memory
   // int AlignCounter[buffer_needed];
   // AlignCounter[0]=0;
   function(AlignCounter);
   free(AlignCounter);

   return 0;
}
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, int* AlignCounter creates a pointer but doesn't allocate anything for it to point to.  Then AlignCounter=0; makes it NULL.  If you're then sending it to align_S_T, you're just referencing a NULL pointer.  Boom.

You probably want to declare int AlignCounter = 0, then send &AlignCounter to your function.